# Liberation Mono has wrong height when highlighted or selected

Tags: 18.04, fonts

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04, something is wrong with my Liberation Mono font.  When selecting text in this font in the browser, it looks like this:

[image: Selected text in Liberation Mono]

This happens in all browsers, across all websites whenever the font is Liberation Mono.  I can also see it in other applications when setting the font to Liberation Mono, so it seems to be an issue with my system.

If I manually change the font to DejaVu Sans Mono (or any other font) on the web page above (GitHub, for what it's worth), the issue immediately goes away:

[image: Selected text in DejaVue Sans Mono]

This issue makes highlighted or selected text in Liberation Mono hard to read.  The font is widely used across the web, e.g. in the text input field I'm just typing this question into, and the cursor is shown far too small.

Do you have any ideas what may be causing this issue, and how to fix it?  I can't simply uninstall the `fonts-liberation` package, since other packages are depending on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a [bug in the `fonts-liberation` and `fonts-liberation2` packages in Ubuntu 18.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1769654).  Installing the bionic-proposed versions of these packages fixed the issue for me.